# Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g: How to see statistics of Interfaces usage?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-enterprise-manager

I need to give our client the following statistics:

- How many users are using the Interfaces or each interface?
- What interfaces are mostly used?
- What are the usual usage time?
- What kind of actions are mostly done?

All this info is needed to show to the client that our product is working.
My question is how to find all this data, numbers and statistics?

Comment: what interface are you talking about? http Endpoints?

Comment: Yes, it is http Endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about Listener statistics on Oracle Enterprise Manager then-

1) Click on Listener name on Home screen of OEM.
[image]

2) Then Click on 'Established Connections per minute' under 'State' section.
[image]

3) Now you have got the page with some statistics of listeners.
[image]

For your last question "What kind of actions are mostly done?" , I think You need to use database auditing so that you can track the activities of users connecting using the listener.